# Upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 on a dual bootable OS: Ubuntu 17.10 and Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, windows-10

I'm currently using dual boot Windows 10 + Ubuntu 17.10. I wanted to upgrade Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04 stable release. By doing so I don't want to harm anything and end up with nothing. I've created live CD for that. Live CD is the only source to upgrade system.

Comment: You should be able to upgrade from 17.10: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_17.10. Any problems with that?

Comment: Is there anyway I can install using live CD. I have created live CD of Ubuntu 18.04. But I'm not sure if that thing is okay! I'll add this new info in question's description. Sorry for inconvenience.